# How to remove rows in R with 0 and get averages of remaining rows

Tags: r, dataframe, average, mean, data-cleaning

I would like to remove all 0's in my data and get the mean across columns for remaining values.

```
dataframe <- ("file.csv")
data_list = lapply (dataframe, read.table, header=TRUE)
```

My dataframe looks like this:

```
A B C
1 0 2
2 1 0
3 3 5
4 7 6
```

I would like my dataframe to look like this

```
A B C
3 3 5
4 7 6
```

I tried

```
dataframe[apply(dataframe[c(1:3)],1,function(z) !any(z==0)),]
```

and got this error

```
Error in apply(dataframe[c(1:3)], 1, function(z) !any(z == 0)) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Additionally, I would like to get the mean of the remaining rows. Again, I am new to scripting altogether and am lost on what to do. I will give more information as needed but this is my full script for now

Answer (score 3):

To remove all the rows that contain zero, you can do

```
df[!rowSums(df == 0), ]
#   A B C
# 3 3 3 5
# 4 4 7 6
```

For the row means of the remaining rows,

```
rowMeans(df[!rowSums(df == 0), ])
#        3        4 
# 3.666667 5.666667
```

where `df` is

```
df <- read.table(text="A B C
1 0 2
2 1 0
3 3 5
4 7 6", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: @RHatesMe - as an alternative, try `rowMeans(na.omit(replace(dat,dat==0,NA)))`